# how do python async behaviour behaves with api requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, api

I've been into Python/Django and things are going good but I'm very curious about how django handle any asynchronous tasks for example if there is a database query that took 10 seconds to execute and another request arrives on the server during these 10 seconds?

```py
def my_api(id):
    do_somthing()
    user = User.objects.get(id=id) # took 10 sec to execute
    do_somthing_with_user()
```

I've used the queryset method that fetch something from database and let's say it took 10 seconds to complete. what happens when another request arrives on the django server, how django respond to it? will the request be pending until the first query responds or will it be handled in a parallel way? what is the deep concept for it?

**How Python Handles these type things under the hood?**

Comment: Common use case for `celery` and `django-celery`, run time consuming tasks async

Comment: @ViaTech I don't want to use external package, I just want to know the default behaviour of python/django in such situations

Answer (score 1):

Handling requests is the main job of the web server that u are using. Django users by default use WSGI/ASGI.

Any requests coming to those web servers have a unique session and it's a separate thread. So no conflicts but there are race conditions. (OS resources, Queue, Stack...)

So consider we have a function that has a 2 seconds sleep inside.

```
import time

def function1():
  time.sleep(2)
```

User 1 and user 2 request to this function by API.(e.x GET test/API)

two threads start for each one and if both almost start at time 0:0:0 then both end like 0:0:2.

So How about Async? Async request work concurrently for each request. (Not Parallel)
assume another API should call that sleepy function twice. (e.x Get test/API2)
The first call would take 2 seconds(Async function and await) and the second call 2 seconds too.
if we called this at 0:0:0 this would be like 0:0:2 again.
In sync way that would be 0:0:4.

So finally how about the Database?
there are many ways to handle that and the popular one is using Database pooling. However, generally, each query request makes a new connection (multi-thread) to the database and runs those stuff.
database pool is a thing that reduces a runtime because it has some ready-to-use connections to the database and whenever it has a job to do it goes and runs the query and back to the place where in without that pool the connection lifetime is over usage and end whenever the job has done.

Comment: like you said, two threads start for each one and if both almost start at time 0:0:0 then both end like 0:0:2.
if thousands request arrives at the same time, will thousands threads be start at 0:0:0 and ends at 0:0:2? wouldn't it be CPU extensive?
I know django will handling it but I'm curious how?

Comment: Cpu intensive tasks depends on core. Too many  request if it has for example computational stuff it wouldn’t end 0:0:2. Django would handle with web server and os. Web server in that case(too many requests) would first add new request to queues then would be down and you would need to buy resources like adding cores and cpus.